# nodejs, use oboe to send large stream or large JSON files have some wrong

Tags: node.js, stream, oboe.js

I send a file from one server(ex:127.0.0.1:3000) to another server(ex:127.0.0.1:3001),I found that when the file is too large, the transfer will be a problem.

for example:

```
//127.0.0.1:3000
router.post('/getStream',function(req, res, next){

function getResultStream(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            oboe('http://127.0.0.1:3001/getEnvelopeResult_2')
                .done(function(things) {
                resolve(things);
            }).node(function(e){
                console.log(e);
            })
            .fail(function(e) {
                console.log(e);
                reject(e);
            });

        });
    }

   getResultStream().then(function(body){
       res.json({data:body});
   }).catch(function(err){
       res.json({message:err});
   });


});
```

for example another server:
I will be to get a json `file.json` and converted into `Stream`.

```
//127.0.0.1:3001
app.get('/getStream',function(req, res, next){

  let path="json/file.json";

  oboe(fs.createReadStream(path))
  .done(function(things) {

    send(things,res);

   })
   .fail(function(e) {
      res.json({message:e});
   });


  function send(things,res){

    things.errorArray = JSON.parse(things.errorArray);
    let json = JSON.stringify(things);
    highland([
      json
    ])
    .invoke('split', [''])
    .sequence()
    .pipe(res)
  }

});
```

the `file.json` approximately 3000 KB in size.
the content like this:

```
{"array":"[{\"No\":1,\"tyep\":\"none\",\"checkflag\":true,\"active\":true,\"time\":\"2017-11-08T07:04:49.024Z\"}...30000 pieces ]
"file":"axzf",
"last":30000,
"start":1
}
```

This `array` for the vast majority of capacity of about 30,000.
I tried 10,000 and 20,000 and 30,000..., is failed.
the `array` only about less than 1100 will be successfully transmitted.

the part of the wrong information:

```
{ statusCode: undefined,
  body: undefined,
  jsonBody: undefined,
  thrown:
   Error: Max buffer length exceeded: textNode
   Ln: 1
   Col: 131072
   Chr: undefined
       at Error (native)
       at emitError
```

---

```
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:188:7)
       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
       at IncomingMessage.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
       at HTTPParser.parserOnBody (_http_common.js:123:22)
       at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:363:20)
       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
       at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
       at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
       at TCP.onread (net.js:547:20) }
```

---

```
 maxActual = Math.max(maxActual, textNode.length);
                                              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at checkBufferLength
```

---

How can I improve, or do I have to do something in other ways if I can not reduce the information?

the highland: http://highlandjs.org/
the oboe: http://oboejs.com/

Answer (score 1):

Hey I see this post is a bit old, but I was having similar issues, and I was able to solve this only using node.

My directory is set up accordingly for this test:

```
.
├── s1
│   └── lorem.txt
├── s2
├── server.js
└── transmitter.js
```

Given that, I was able to solve this using the following code:

#### transmitter.js

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const requestOpts = {
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: 1337,
  method: 'POST'
};

const readStream = fs.createReadStream('./s1/lorem.txt');
const request = http.request(requestOpts);

readStream.pipe(request);
```

#### server.js

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

http.createServer((request, response) => {
  const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./s2/lorem.txt');

  request.on('data', (chunk) => {
    writeStream.write(chunk);
  });

  request.on('end', () => {
    writeStream.close();
    response.end();
  });
}).listen(1337);
```

You can test this by running `node server.js` in one terminal window, and, in another, running `transmitter.js`.

The result should be `lorem.txt` appearing in the `s2` directory exactly as it appears in `s1`.

Obviously there's a lot more to be done to make this production worthy, but hopefully that helps the next person to wander through here as I did.